# Disabling a link in ng-repeat list

Tags: angularjs

I have used `ng-repeat` to display a set of values as hyperlink which further opens related data in very next DIV. Now when I click on the link, after loading data in respective div, how can I disable the clicked link?

Comment: please provide plunkr link

Comment: by using index of map javascript function , I could manage to disable the link.Thank you.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea that you pay a visit to StackOverflow's rules and guides on how to post a question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.items = [
    {name:'First', descr:'First Description'},
    {name:'Second', descr:'Second Description'},
    {name:'Third', descr:'Third Description'}
  ]
  var visited = [];
  $scope.act = function(item){
    if(visited.indexOf(item.name) == -1){
      item.dis = true;
      $scope.active = item;
      visited.push(item.name);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.dis {
  color: currentColor;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <a ng-class='{dis:x.dis}' ng-repeat-start='x in items' href='#' ng-click='act(x)'>
    {{x.name}}  
  </a>
  <br ng-repeat-end>
  <div>
    {{active.descr}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Slava Utesinov! :-)